# PHP function get checkboxes value

Tags: php, html

I'm currently creating a website for a local sports union, so far I have created numerous pages, one of them being a table with the members and their information. Each member has a checkbox that contains the email address as a value. I should add that at the moment the members information is viewed in members.php, but the file that gets the information (The code you can see below) is from backend file fetch.php.
What I want is that when you check multiple checkboxes and press 'Send Mail', it should open a mailto:?bcc=mail1,mail2 etc.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result))
{
    echo "<form method=\"post\">";
    // Printing user information etc.
    echo "<td><input name=\"email[]\" type=\"checkbox\" class=\"email-cb\" value=\"$email\"></td>";
    echo "<tr><td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Send Mail\"></td></tr>";
    echo "</form>"
}
```

First of when you press the submit button (Or Send Mail if you like), it should simply do Send Mail

I have been working on this for a while and can't seem to find a solution, anyways I came up with this method to atleast extract emails (I think this is correct).

```
if(isset($_POST['email']) && is_array($_POST['email']))
{
    foreach($_POST['email'] as $email)
    {
        $emailList = "mailto:?bcc=" . implode(',', $_POST['email']);
    }
}
```

Comment: means without setting email? it is submitting form ?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. You don't set the email, the emails are gathered from an MySQL server with the members information, and the emails are stored in the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$_POST['fruit']` to `$_POST['email']`, and you don't need the loop, because the post data is already an array.:

```
if(isset($_POST['email']) && is_array($_POST['email']))
{
    $emailList = "mailto:?bcc=" . implode(',', $_POST['email']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does $_POST['fruit']?? Maybe you are looking for this:

```
if(isset($_POST['email']) && is_array($_POST['email']))
{
    foreach($_POST['email'] as $email)
    {
        $bccList .= $email.',';
    }
    $emailList = "mailto:?bcc=" . $bccList;
}
```

Comment: Ah yea, I forgot to edit that. I got inspiration from another post that used fruit as example.